# How to search union query by to dates in MS Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, search, union

I have a form with two textboxes and two cmd buttons (one to search and the other to delete)

When I enter the two dates the union query works well (see qry4). See code below:

```
SELECT tblwrkday2.DATE, tblwrkday2.name, tblwrkday2.qty
FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.DATE) BETWEEN [Forms] ! [frm_Search] ! [txtday1] 
AND [Forms] ! [frm_Search] ! [txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name

UNION

SELECT tblwrkdays3.DATE, tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.DATE) BETWEEN [Forms] ! [frm_Search] ! [txtday1] 
AND [Forms] ! [frm_Search] ! [txtday2]));
```

However, I need data as shown in "qry4_expected".
[image]

I have been searching the web with no success.

Any help is welcome.

The first code:

```
SELECT columns
FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.Datte
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name
UNION SELECT tblwrkdays3.Date, tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]));
```

My second code:

```
SELECT columns
FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.Datte
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name
UNION SELECT tblwrkdays3.Date, tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]));
```

My third code

```
    SELECT columns
FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.Datte AND ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name
UNION SELECT tblwrkdays3.Date, tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.Date) Between [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Formularios]![frm_Search]![txtday2]));
```

All SQL failed to displays data as shown on the right side of the image.

Any idea is welcome.

Finally, I found the code. I move column name to the left and the query works. Ths is the SQL code:

```
SELECT tblwrkday2.name, tblwrkday2.Datte, tblwrkday2.qty
FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.Datte) Between [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name
UNION SELECT tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.Datte, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.Datte) Between [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday2]));
```

Comment: Well. Since I uploaded my question, I have been testing and SQL to order by mane and Datte. Below I include the three SQL codes that unfortunately faliled

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the code (included below. I just move name field as the first column and ordered it, ascendent.

```
SELECT tblwrkday2.name, tblwrkday2.Datte, tblwrkday2.qty
```

FROM tblwrkday2
WHERE (((tblwrkday2.Datte) Between [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday2]))
ORDER BY tblwrkday2.name
UNION SELECT tblwrkdays3.name, tblwrkdays3.Datte, tblwrkdays3.qty
FROM tblwrkdays3
WHERE (((tblwrkdays3.Datte) Between [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday1] And [Forms]![frm_Search]![txtday2]));

Cheers